# What does Tenri whisper to Diana?

Tags: the-world-god-only-knows

In episode 12, season 3 of the anime The World God Only Knows, there's a scene at around 5:14 where Tenri speaks to Diana and tells her something surprising. Diana responds by exclaiming why Tenri didn't say anything before.

The next time we see Diana she has wings.

I'm guessing Tenri told Diana something that would promote their relationship with Keima, because she grew wings, but since Diana has been with Tenri ever since she was a little girl, I'm not sure what Tenri could've told Diana that would be so surprising.

Comment: Which season of the anime is this from? I'm guessing the third season but I don't remember too well which had what content.

Comment: It's the third season.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting as answer because can't use spoilers in comments, still just a speculation...

With the recent development in the manga, it seems it might be something along the lines of:

> Keima is the one that chose me to be your host

Also, remember Diana grew her wings once before (although they didn't notice), in manga Chapter 139 (can't remember which episode), after Keima apologizes to her in his library.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to keep the spoiler at minimum. This is from Heart of Jupiter Arc, the last arc of the series.

What she said to Diana is...
[image]
<sub>From TWGOK Chapter 191 A Girl. Page 13</sub>

> This arc tells about Keima being sent to the past. Tenri probably explained Diana about the event that happen 10 years ago, about how Tenri and Keima got involved with the mass escape of the runaway spirits, and how it will affect the future.

Answer (score 3):

In the bath scene in episode 9, at 12:01, Diana confessess to Keima (Diana likes Keima). Tenri asks why she is there at 13:00. At 13:40, Diana encourages Tenri to confess.

**Tenri PROBABLY doesn't love Keima as much as Diana thought she did. Tenri might have said she doesn't like Keima.**

With Tenri's confession to Diana in episode 12, Diana grew her wings.

From a common viewer.

Comment: Tenri does have feelings for Keima, that much could be seen when she went to his house to cheer him up after him dealing with Chihiro.

Comment: Also, now that the manga has finished, we can see that Tenri's reaction in the final chapter suggests this isn't the answer.